# Что означает запись в go?

Tags: функции, golang

Искал примеры реализации десктоп-приложений в go, наткнулся на запись вида

```
func (ap *AppGUI) Run() { }
```

`AppGUI` - Структура (`struct`). Что это за обращение? Каким образом можно обратится к этой функции, если обращение вида `Run()` - выдает ошибку `undefined function`?

Comment: Через структуру и обратиться https://metanit.com/go/tutorial/4.4.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, Вы впервые увидели вызов ["метода"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

Как вызвать? нужно иметь объект нужного типа и у него уже позвать.

```
AppGUI app
app.Run()
```